# FTP Upload via PHP Script not working, but ftp_mkdir is working

Tags: php, upload, ftp

I am trying to upload a file to an FTP Server via a PHP script. The connection works and I can create subdirectories on the server. However ftp_put gives the following error:

**Warning: ftp_nb_put() [function.ftp-nb-put]: php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115) in ...**

**Warning: ftp_nb_put() [function.ftp-nb-put]: Type set to I in ....**

This is the script

```
$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftpHost);#
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftpUser, $ftpPw);

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);


// Verbindung überprüfen
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result))
    {
    // no Connection

    }else{
    // Connection WORKS!

    if(!@ftp_chdir ( $conn_id , $ftpDir )){
        // ftp_mkdir WORKS!
            @ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $ftpDir);
        }//if(!@ftp_chdir ( $conn_id , $ftpDir )){


    if (ftp_put($conn_id, $myFile, $targetfile, FTP_BINARY)) {
                 // Upload success: NOT WORKING!

            }       


    }

}//if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result))
```

How can I change my script to get my desired behaviour?

Comment: where is $myFile, $targetfile defined? where is the part to change dir when you creating a dir? why do you use @ to suppress warnings and notices?

Comment: try it with passive mode off by using `false` in second parameter of `ftp_pasv` function. If it works, then it means you are behind the firewall.

Comment: 'ftp_pasv' 'false' does not working. @donald123: the files are available and everything works on my private demo FTP Server, but not on the live system.

Comment: This is FTPS, not SFTP. They are very different things.

Comment: Do you have an access to FTP server log? Can you share it?

Comment: I don't have access to FTP logs. But for me it seems to be strange, that I can connect to the SFTP Server and that I can create directories. That works. But the upload is not working...

Comment: It's actually very common with FTP (not SFTP, you keep confusing that), because file transfers with FTP require a separate data transfer connection, what is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide us much useful information, I can only suggest that this is a network issue that prevents opening a data transfer connection.

For details refer to my article on [FTP connection modes and necessary network configuration](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).

*If you provide more details, like an FTP server log or any kind of network log (e.g. from Wireshark), you will likely get more concrete answers.*